# Parsing JSON String containing multiple objects

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, json

I am retrieving json data from a url. The json "string" has one object that contains multiple objects inside of it, each of of the objects containing their own key, value properties...essentially the json object is an NSArray containing objects that are more or less dictionary objects. I'm trying to use NSJSONSerialization but there isn't a lot of documentation on it, and I can't seem to figure out how to Here is an example of what the json might look like:

```
{"allObjects":[{"firstName":"homer","middleName":"j","lastName":"simpson"
,"address": "123 evergreen terrace","countryCode":"US","zip":12345},
{"firstName": "marge","middleName":"b","lastName":"simpson","address":
"123 evergreen terrace","countryCode":"US","zip":12345}]}
```

(If it matters, the JSON object contains MANY more entries)

Are there specific "options" I need to use with NSJSONSerialization to get an array of dictionaries out (the array being "allObjects")?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

This code results in an error:

@vishy I thought this too, but when I run this code,

```
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:geoNamesJSON options: kNilOptions error:&error];
NSDictionary *dict = [json objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *allKeys = [dict allKeys];
NSString *key = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSEnumerator *keyEnum = [allKeys objectEnumerator];
NSLog(@"All keys in the first dictionary object:");
while(key = [keyEnum nextObject]){
    NSLog(@"%@", key);}
```

I get this error:

> -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1fd7cd10
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary
>   objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1fd7cd10'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x3796c2a3 0x35c7c97f 0x3796fe07 0x3796e531 0x378c5f68 0xf310b 0xf219d 0x38ca4321 0x38cdecfd 0x38d53cc1
>   0x38cd86a7 0x38cd8481 0x38c52abb 0x38cc78d7 0x355b9bd9 0x3665c4b7
>   0x366611bd 0x3793ff3b 0x378b2ebd 0x378b2d49 0x37def2eb 0x38c91301
>   0xd3551 0x3c39db20) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an
>   exception (lldb)

Comment: in the given json- it is a dictionary with one object within it their is an array of 2 dictionaries..
to parse any json u should be knowing the format of ur json & then only u can write ur parsing code..

Comment: @vishy I updated my question (can't figure out the mini-Markdown) with the issue using this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting any values in array after doing this step

```
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:geoNamesJSON options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

i dont think so, as your json is a dictionary. It should be

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:geoNamesJSON options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

For info on handling json you can follow this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5).

**Edit**: Parse the data in this way after getting the json dictionary using above lines

```
NSArray* geoList = [geoDict objectForKey:@"geonames"];
NSLog(@"first object in geolist--%@",[geoList objectAtIndex:0]);
//each object in the array is a dictionary
```

Comment: as u get dictionary after serialization u can print & check in which format is it.. can u show dat log..?

Comment: geonames =     (
                {
            adminCode1 = *OMITTED*
            adminName1 = *OMITTED*
            countryCode = *OMITTED*
            countryName = *OMITTED*
            distance = "*OMITTED*";
            fcl = *OMITTED*;
            fclName = "*OMITTED*";
            fcode = *OMITTED*;
            fcodeName = *OMITTED*;
            geonameId = *OMITTED*;
            lat = "*OMITTED*";
            lng = "*OMITTED*";
            name = "*OMITTED*";
            population = 0;
            toponymName = *OMITTED*;
        });

Comment: what are '=' here.. & wat is 'geonames' according to this the json has only one dictionary, which as strings(objects) & keys..

Comment: I simply did as you asked. First I did: NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:geoNamesJSON options: kNilOptions error:&error]; NSLog(@"%@", json);

Comment: i have some doubts... check my comments above

Comment: Here's the code: NSData *geoNamesJSON = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    
    NSError *error;
    
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:geoNamesJSON options: kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@", json);

and here's a link to the JSON:
[link](http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyJSON?username=jpcguy89&maxRows=30&featureCode=GDN&featureCode=RESN&featureCode=RES&featureCode=PRK&lat=41.890912&lng=-87.921091&radius=48)

Comment: Then, as i said it is only 1 dictionary key 'geonames'.. parse the objects from key using `NSDictionary* dict = [json objectForKey:@"geonames"]; NSString* str = [dict objectForKey:@"adminCode1"];` check this..

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized

Comment: I'm so confused...it works for objectAtIndex:0, but anything further gets NSRangeException (in this case...) index (1) BeyondBounds.

Just to be clear, I created a dictionary from the data taken from the url using NSJSONSerialization called geoDict, and then created an array from geoDict called geoList using [geoDict objectForKey:@"geonames"];, and finally printed out an object in the newly created array using NSLog(@"first object in geolist--%@", objectAtIndex:0); (I got the error when I used 1 for the index.

Comment: geoList count is 1. Could it be that the parser doesn't like the way the JSON is formatted from the url?

Comment: am getting 30 objects here.. check out the sample here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58723521/samples/ModalViewTest.zip once u run the code, after button tap the list is logged in console..

Comment: That's interesting...apparently, the difference between 30 results and 1 result is a format string vs. the entire string without format. I'm constructing the string from url elements using (I have to by nature of my app), [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&featureCode=GDN&featureCode=RESN&featureCode=RES&featureCode=PRK%@%@", URL_PREFIX, lat, lng]]. But why would this make a difference? I'm taking the strings directly from the call, and not initializing them into new strings first, could that be it?

Comment: I'm an IDIOT. When I printed out the url to test the results via the browser (which I gave you), I missed the fact that I had included radius there (which is what makes it return multiple returns) but I DIDN'T put include it in the ACTUAL STRING that I used to make the URL, to get the data.

Comment: Thank you for all your help and cooperation. Sorry for wasting your time, but you did in the end solve it for me!

Comment: ok, no problem.. hav u checked my sample.. u got it from their?